# windows visual studio git configuration can not change remote to use https

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio, https

cannot do a pull from a simple repository as Git says I do not have rights! no problem from my main development machine and then I noticed on the machine that fails it wants to use SSH as this image show[image: my settings]s

so I used the edit dialog to try changing to https://github.com/jmcfet/onthespotaugust18

but Visual studio keeps resetting to git@gthub.com ..... I tried doing the following :
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
but no help

Answer (score 0):

turns out my problem was in gitconfig file that was resisting attempts to reset to HTTPS from SSH. Have no idea how it got stuck on SSH but I blew away the file in my user/ME folder and copied the file from a machine that worked and now functions as expected. wasted way too much time on this. Git is a great tool but too easy to get in weird states